# Definition of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

So I've just picked up learning topology and metric spaces and i am very confused on the definition of open sets in a topology.
I always thought that every set in a topology was open by definition so I was quite confused to see that when considering the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ i saw on a youtube video that the singletons for example $[0]$ is closed so it cannot be in the topology.
So does this mean that singletons are closed?.
However we can have singleton sets in a topology when considering a different set not the reals so what is going on why are singletons not included in the topology of the reals and what topology would we use on $\mathbb{R}$?.
This is probably a stupid question for most of you but im completely new and all these concepts baffle me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the usual topology, open subsets of $\mathbb R$ are unions of open intervals, so singletons and closed intervals are not open; $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$ are both open and closed

Comment: So the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain singletons?

Comment: The usual topology on $\mathbb R$ does not contain singletons.  The topology that contains singletons is the [discrete topology](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Topology_Discrete_iff_All_Singletons_Open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of a topology , the sets in it are going to be the open sets. And by definition the closed sets are going to be the complements of the open sets but it all depends on the choice of topology. A space can have a lot of topologies. In your video most likely you were working with the metric topology and there yes we do have that singletons are closed sets. But I could very well be working in the discrete topology were every set is open and closed, it all depends on the choice of topology . You can have singletons closed or open or both or neither it all depends in the choice of topology.

But yes most of the times people are working on what is called the metric topology of $\mathbb{R}$, for example when we do standard analysis we use this topology, and most of the times don't even  mention it.

I would recommend for you to take a look at Munkres' Topology; in my opinion the concepts are well explained and the initial part is easy for self-learning.